# Enabling HTTPS / 2 Way SSL Communication between Ethereum / Quorum Nodes

Tags: quorum

To further enhance security and comply to regulatory requirements, there is a need to enable HTTPS / 2 Way SSL Communication between Ethereum / Quorum Nodes.

Understand that Quorum uses existing Ethereum p2p transport layer to communicate transactions between nodes, but communicate blocks only through the Raft transport layer.

Can all the communication between nodes and between client and node be SSL enabled for regulatory reasons?

Answer (score 0):

This feature is now being considered as an enhancement in Quorum.

https://github.com/jpmorganchase/quorum/issues/477

Comment: It has almost been 2 years, is https connection possible with Quorum Nodes now? If yes, which version of Quorum & geth to be used.

Comment: Also, is https connection to Node via web3 possible?